# R's: Trilled R, Uvular Fricative R, and Uvular Trill R

Tags: pronunciation, bavarian

I've read that the Bavarian accent (or the southern regions in general) uses a trilled R -- IPA [r] -- instead of the "standard" voiced uvular fricative -- IPA [ʁ]. I've also read that the uvular trill -- IPA [ʀ] -- is how they pronounce R's in Switzerland.

So I have a couple questions about this situation:

1. Would using a trilled R give a learner a marked Bavarian accent?
2. Is having a marked Bavarian accent a bad thing?
3. How "bad" is it to pronounce the uvular R as a trill instead of a fricative?

Basically, I can easily pronounce the trilled R from my Spanish experience, and I can sorta do the uvular trill like in French, but the standard uvular fricative is still difficult for me. So I'm looking for guidance on **which "temporary" pronunciation I should favor while I practice the standard R**.

Comment: +1 for your effort to study German so deliberately. My impression is that people are very, very relaxed about the *R* usage.

Comment: I studied linguistics in college; I can't help myself. ;)

Comment: French doesn't have an uvular trill, it has an uvular fricative. For me the fricative is pretty easy but the trill is extremely difficult even though I can produce other trills such as the Spanish one. -- Correction: Wikipedia says French does have it in some dialects though I've only heard it in German.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1.) Would using a trilled R give a learner a marked Bavarian accent?

No. The most distinct characteristic of Bavarian is its pronunciation of vowels (especially diphthongs). Without them, you won't sound Bavarian at all.

> 2.) Is having a marked Bavarian accent a bad thing?

Really, *really* depends on where you're going. Some people are pretty hostile when it comes to Bavarian and in some situations any dialect might just be considered too informal.  But I don't think you'll ever going to have this problem. At least if you're not learning German in Bavaria from the scratch - I've heard some funny stories about foreign looking people with strong Bavarian accent. Will give you some startled looks usually. :-)

> 3.) How "bad" is it to pronounce the uvular R as a trill instead of a fricative?

It's really one of the minor mistakes. Most people won't even notice. Worst that can happen to you is that people find it charming. ;-)

Comment: +1 for "most people won't even notice". There are so many dialects using trilled 'R'.

Comment: There are even a few dialects using ɻ (American English style R). That's something I wouldn't recommend, though. Has kind of a negative touch and sticks out.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed anwser! I think I'll keep working at the uvular R and not worry too much if it's a trill more often than it's a fricative for now. :)

Answer (score 5):

German /r/ can be pronounced as /R/ (uvular trill), /ʁ/ (fricative), and in some accents /r/ (/r/ is not very common). There is probably not any logical distribution of regions with a uvular trill versus fricative as in French, as it seems to be in free variation in German (it is very obvious in some languages when the sound is a uvular trill versus fricative because the fricative can be devoiced to a voiceless uvular fricative /X/, whereas the trill is less likely to). The difference between /R/ and /ʁ/ is not really noticeable, because in all environments where /ʁ/ would be devoiced (e.g. at the coda of a syllable before a voiceless consonant) the /R/ or /ʁ/ becomes a totally different allophone. For example, the /R/ in "warten" is not even pronounced as /R/ because it occurs in coda position. If it were pronounced as /ʁ/ it would theoretically be devoiced, but because German does not allow coda /R/ or /ʁ/ it is almost impossible for phoneticians to know whether it is a trill or fricative just by listening. The sounds are very difficult to distinguish by the human ear (except maybe /R/ can be longer), and you really would to analyze a spectrogram to come up with a concrete conclusion, unless the speaker was exaggerating the sounds so that the difference was obvious.

Basically, both the trill and fricative work in onset position (not at the end of a syllable), and it is almost impossible for the human ear to distinguish. People with large uvula's probably make something which sounds more like /R/ because the uvula would flap around automatically while making frication noise. Just don't pronounce "r" as a trill or fricative at the end of a syllable.

Answer (score -3):

I would say both ways to pronounce an r are correct.

I think not mixing up the two pronunciations of **o** which are not differentiated in writing is more important than the pronunciations of **r**.

Example.

open like in `die Woche`  [ˈvɔxə]

or closed like `oder`     [ˈoːdər]

---

BTW: I use this [online dictionary](http://www.wissen.de/wde/generator/wissen/services/suche/wb/index.html) to find the phonetic spelling.

Comment: How does this connect to the question?

Comment: Different spellings of r's are rather unimportant

Comment: Do you mean it's more important to learn to properly differentiate open and closed vowels? Then you should say that in your answer `:-)` (Incidentally, I think you mean _pronunciations_ and not _spellings_ in your comment.)

Comment: @Hendrik Thanks for correction. That's one I easily confuse.